# Resizing tkinter windows and contents

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python tkinter to build a ui containing a matplotlib figure and some buttons, but am having difficulty with resizing the window and it's contents. I've looked at some of the examples on this site and the docs and as I understand it, for a frame containing smaller frames to resize together they all need to be configured individually. Each one gets a weight applied to it to define how much of the available space it receives (is this correct?). However, when I try to apply this as shown below none of the frames resize.
Also if the wiegth is zero for columnconfigure and 1 for row configure does that mean it will only resize in one direction?

```
import Tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
class Application():
    def __init__(self, master):


        frame2 = Tkinter.Frame(master, height=510, width=770, bg='red')
        frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        frame2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        frame2a = Tkinter.Frame(frame2, height=80, width=770, bg='blue') 
        frame2a.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        frame2a.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame2a.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)        

        frame2b = Tkinter.Frame(frame2, height=410, width=770, bg='green') 
        frame2b.grid(row=1, column= 0, sticky='nsew')
        frame2b.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame2b.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)    

        # add plot
        fig = Figure(figsize=(9.5,5.2), facecolor='white')
        fig.add_subplot(111)        
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame2b)

        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("770x510")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach using `columnconfigure` and `rowconfigure` is correct, but you forgot one thing: You haven't used the methods on the *master* window. So, you basically want to do this:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

To answer your other question (*Also if the wiegth is zero for columnconfigure and 1 for row configure does that mean it will only resize in one direction?*): Yes, you're right, the widget/window would extend in just one or none direction then.

Additionally, since you are using `grid` for dynamic resizing, the `height` and `width` parameters are obsolete.

Comment: I would add: if you mix and match `.pack()' and `.grid()`, and place gridded widgets _inside_ a packed widget, you must apply  `.columnconfigure` and `.rowconfigure` to that packed widget too. Otherwise, the packed widget will not dynamically resize for its (gridded) child items. This was counter-interintuitive to me, as I initially believed that packed objects could not take the `.columnconfigure` and `.rowconfigure` methods (as those are used for gridded items normally).

Answer (score 0):

The `rowconfigure` needs to be applied to the container, not to the contained objects.  You have `frame 2` containing `frame2a` and `frame2b`.  So along with `frame2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)`, giving a weight of 1 to row 0 (i.e. to `frame2a`), you need to add `frame2.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)` to weight the other row equally.  On the other hand, the four lines of code of the form `frame2[ab].[row|column]configure(...)` are redundant.