# Make Tkinter window resize and adjust window contents dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is it possible to make tkinter window's contents adjust to screen size? Like if I had made a window according to a screen resolution of 1366x768, and then I run the same code on a system of 1024x768 resolution and make its contents resize dynamically? I know I can use grid structure as [as described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751730/resizing-tkinter-windows-and-contents) here and set the weight of cells accordingly. But is it possible with pack geometry structure and not grid? I am asking this since half of the project I am working on was made by my colleague and he didn't use grid at all. So instead of redoing all of the code in grid, I am looking for a way around it. Here is the sample code I need to resize -

```
def container(self):
    frame_number_panel = tk.Frame(self.parent, width=round(Dimension.SCREEN_WIDTH*0.8), height=Dimension.SCREEN_HEIGHT, bg="#eeeeee")
    frame_number_panel.pack(side="left", anchor=W)
    frame_number_panel.pack_propagate(False)
    self.main_container(frame_number_panel)
    
    # right side pannel
    frame_right_side_panel = tk.Frame(self.parent, bg="#101115", width=round(Dimension.SCREEN_WIDTH*0.2), height=Dimension.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    frame_right_side_panel.pack(side="right", anchor=NE)
    frame_right_side_panel.pack_propagate(False)
    frame_first_row = tk.Frame(frame_right_side_panel, bg="#101115")
    frame_first_row.pack()

    winning_claim_image = PhotoImage(file=ResourcePath.resource_path('images/icon_win_claim.png'))
    label_winning_claim = tk.Label(frame_first_row, bg="#fcd116", text="WINNING\nCLAIM", image=winning_claim_image,
                                   compound="left", fg="#231f20", font=("Roboto-Bold", 10, "bold"),
                                   width=Dimension.label_winning_claim_width,
                                   height=Dimension.label_winning_claim_height)
    label_winning_claim.image = winning_claim_image
    label_winning_claim.pack(side="left", padx=Dimension.label_winning_claim_padx)

    reprint_image = PhotoImage(file=ResourcePath.resource_path('images/reprint_2.png'))
    label_reprint = tk.Label(frame_first_row, bg="#8ac539", text="REPRINT", image=reprint_image,
                             compound="left", fg="#231f20", font=("Roboto-Bold", 10, "bold"),
                             width=Dimension.label_winning_claim_width, height=Dimension.label_winning_claim_height)
    label_reprint.image = reprint_image
    label_reprint.pack(side="left", padx=Dimension.label_winning_claim_padding)
```

as you can see all the widgets are placed using pack geometry manager.

Comment: Look at `pack` [documentation](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm), there is the `expand` option for resizing.

Comment: I believe your question is how to make the window resize its contents dynamically on different monitors?

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve nearly the same with `pack` than with `grid`. Indeed, I usually prefer the packing, since it gives me more freedom.

For instance, take the following example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, X, Frame, Y, LEFT, BOTH

root = Tk()

# Initialize frames
f1 = Frame(root, bg="grey")
f2 = Frame(root, bg="pink")

# Initialize labels
w1 = Label(f1, text="Red", bg="red", fg="white")
w2 = Label(f1, text="Green", bg="green", fg="white")
w3 = Label(f1, text="Blue", bg="blue", fg="white")
w1b = Label(f2, text="Red", bg="red", fg="white")
w2b = Label(f2, text="Green", bg="green", fg="white")
w3b = Label(f2, text="Blue", bg="blue", fg="white")

# Packing level 1
f1.pack(fill=X)
f2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

# Packing level 2
w1.pack(fill=X)
w2.pack(fill=X)
w3.pack(fill=X)
w1b.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
w2b.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
w3b.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

As you can see, by using the parameters `fill` and `expand` in the correct way, I have set the second frame to be expandable with the windows on both sides (`X` and `Y`), while the first frame is only expandable in `X`. All the labels inside the frames are also equally distributed.

See all the options of `pack` in the documentation: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm.

Comment: My primary concern is, if I have tested it on a 1366x768 environment, and then I try to run the same code in a smaller resolution environment, say, 1024x768, will the content inside the frame adjust accordingly? Like buttons, labels, entries etc? Because with my current code, one frame expands too much and the right side frame just goes out of screen and isnt visible anymore

Comment: Yes, they will resize accordingly. As you can see in my example, the labels are equally distributed inside the frame regardless of its size. In this case, I needed to use `expand=True` for such a behavior on the second frame.

Comment: Ok,  I will try this solution and let you know.

Comment: I get that in f1 and f2 all the Labels are of same size, but is it possible to make f1 occupy screen size in some percentage? Like f1 to be of 30% of the screen and f2 to be 70%? I am asking this because my code will be running on several devices with all of them having different resolutions.

Comment: I think this answer may be useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383101/tkinter-percentage-sizes

Comment: I tried with the % symbol in width and height, it just gives an error